# Laravel global function

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have 2 models:

**Bill:**
id, account_id,  descripcion, monto_pagado, saldo

**Payment:**
id, bill_id, monto

Each time someone insert a new bill to the account or insert a new payment I pretend to calculate the balance of the account.

What would be the best place to accomplish this:

- as service
- as mutators in the model
- as function in the controller

I know i would have to call this in others places of my project. So i would like it to be a global function. What would be the best place to do it?

Comment: create a class, inject it in any class you need then use $this->billing($somthing);  this is the best simple way as far as i know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use an event in your models. Use `creating` if you want to calculate before the model is actually created in the database, or `created` if you want to calculate after it has been created.

In your App\Providers\AppServiceProvider::boot() method, define the events for both models:

```
class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    public function boot()
    {
        Bill::creating(function ($bill) {
            // Do something with $bill
        });
    }

    // etc
}
```

To avoid code repetition, you may use a trait and use it in both classes. Call it `PretendCalculationTrait` for example and place it in `app/Traits` (create the directory if needed):

```
<?php

namespace App\Traits;

trait PretendCalculationTrait
{
    public function pretendCalculate()
    {
        // Do your stuff
    }
}
```

Then in your model, use this trait:

```
class Bill extends Eloquent
{
    use App\Traits\PretendCalculationTrait;

    // etc.
}
```

Finally, in your AppServiceProvider, call the method defined in the trait:

```
public function boot()
{
    Bill::creating(function ($bill) {
        return $bill->pretendCalculate();
    });

    Payment::creating(function ($payment) {
        return $payment->pretendCalculate();
    });
}
```

See Laravel [Model Events](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent#events) documentation for more details.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution, since you mentioned wanting it to be a global function, is to use Laravel's autoloading feature.

Create a file that contains the function for your calculation. It can be placed anywhere, and contain other functions, but for brevity we'll place it here: `App/Http/customFunctions.php`. In your file, create your function:

```
function pretendCalculation()
{
    return $something;
}
```

Next, tell Laravel to autoload it by adding it to your autoloading list in `composer.json`:

```
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "database"
    ],
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/"
    },
    "files": [
        "app/Http/customFunctions.php" <-- Here is the new file
    ]
```

Then just execute a `composer dump auto-load -o` or the like, and now you'll have access to this file/all functions within the file, anywhere in your application.